# Can Perl 6 use the % sigil for something other than a Hash?

Tags: associative, raku

The Perl 6 docs on variables notes that the `%` sigil can be used with types that do the [Associative](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Associative) role. It specifically mentions [Pair](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Pair), [Hash](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Hash), and [Map](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Map). But, how would I get a [Pair](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Pair) into a variable with the `%`?

If I use a type constraint I get a curious error:

```
> my Pair %pair = Pair.new( 'a', 'b' )
Type check failed in assignment to %pair; expected Pair but got Str ("b")
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

If I assign without the type constraint I get a hash:

```
my %pair = Pair.new: 'a', 'b';  # Hash, not Pair
```

Binding works:

```
my %pair := Pair.new: 'a', 'b';  # Pair
```

But if I use a type constraint, I get another curious error:

```
> my Pair %p2 := Pair.new: 'a', 'b';
Type check failed in binding; expected Associative[Pair] but got Pair (:a("b"))
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1
```

The same problem shows up with [Bag](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Bag) and [Set](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Set). Do it with [Map](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Map) and you end up with a mutable [Hash](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Hash).

I figure there's a variety of issues here, but perhaps the `%` sigil isn't as versatile as I was led to believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `%` sigiled containers to hold any value that `does` the [`Associative`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Associative) Role.

You must be careful, as you discovered, in how you declare and assign.

In your example, `my Pair %pair`, you are saying to make a `Hash` (not a `Pair`) that can hold `Pair` values (`%pair.WHAT = 'Hash[Pair]'`)

Try this:

```
my Pair %p2 = mykey => Pair.new: 'a', 'b';
```

which can be nice.  By constraining the type of values, you'll get an error if you say

```
%p2<c> = 'd';
```

since you're not assigning a `Pair`.

Binding, as you also discovered, works the way you think it should.

Comment: Honestly, you can just use `$` for everything and ignore `%` and `@` if you like.  The best use of them IMHO is in Signatures -- they make it trivial to constrain the type of things that can get passed in to something that `does` `Associative` or `does` `Positional` without overly restricting them to, say `Array` or `Hash`, since someone might want to use other fancy or even homegrown types, but you really only care about the interface to the class--the `Role`--not precisely which type it is.

Comment: Really?  Not close?  The binding will work the way you think it should, and I thought I explained pretty clearly your misconceptions in the OP.  The comment also explains how the sigils can be very useful in Signatures.  What isn't clear?

Comment: Right, I pointed out that your example was making hashes that hold pairs--not what you wanted--and that binding worked, as you discovered.  Signatures are also a good way to make variables that can receive any type that does the Role, exactly what you asked.

Comment: My apologies if you didn't find it useful.  It is just another example of the versatility and usefulness of the `%` sigil others finding this page might find helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144694/discussion-between-curt-tilmes-and-brian-d-foy).

Answer (score 9):

We need to take a few steps back if we want to understand what is happening with your examples:

Variables are bound to objects. By default, sigilled variables are initially bound to assignable container objects (`Scalar` for `$` and `&`, `Array` for `@` and `Hash` for `%`).

If you add a type to a variable declaration such as

```
my Int %var
```

or equivalently

```
my %var of Int
```

you place a restriction on the types of values this container may hold.

Variable assignment (`=`) tries to put the value on the right hand side into the container bound to the variable on the left-hand side, which will fail if this type constraint isn't satisfied. By default, only `&` variables come with such a constraint (cf `(my &).VAR.of` vs `(my %).VAR.of`).

In contrast, rebinding a variable (`:=`) will replace the container object. If you want to place restrictions on which types of objects can be bound, you need `is` instead if `of`:

```
my %var is Pair;
%var := x => 1; # ok
%var := 42;     # not ok
```

Sigilled variables imply default type contraints (none for `$`, `Callable` for `&`, `Positional` for `@` and `Associative` for `%`). Note that this default constraint gets overriden by an explicit one, eg

```
my %var is Int;
%var := 42; # ok even though 42 is not Associative
```

Finally, note that `is` doesn't merely set the type constraint, but will also bind the variable to a newly created instance of that type:

```
my %pair is Pair;
say %pair; # (Mu) => (Mu), ie Pair.new()
```

I'm not aware  of any way to just do the former.

Comment: 'Sigilled variables imply default type contraints ... this default constraint gets overriden by an explicit one, eg `my %var is Int;`' Presumably this is a bug, i.e. P6 should reject binding a value that does not do Associative to a `%foo` identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, this feels like a bug to me. `%` containers have no problem storing a `Pair` that is constructed via the fat arrow infix constructor:

```
my %pair = what => 'a pair';
```

The container overrides the type though, so you get a `Hash` rather than a `Pair`.

```
%pair.WHAT; #=> (Hash)
```